# Read/write Excel 2007 password-protected documents

Tags: c#, excel, encryption, ms-office, password-protection

What method does Office 2007 use for encryption (when choosing Encrypt and setting a password from Office menu)?

My C# app needs to create and read encrypted Excel 2007 files (.xlsx). It is important that these files remain accessible from Excel, so I must use Microsoft's encryption method, can't brew my own.

Normal Excel 2007 file is a ZIP-compressed file, and I'm accessing it using [ExcelPackage](http://excelpackage.codeplex.com), which internally uses * System.Io.Packaging.Package* (part of .net 3.0).

However, the encryption in Office is **not** the standard ZIP encryption. The Package class seems not to support encryption, and reports a corrupted file. 7Zip opens the file (with no password provided) and shows a few binary files inside.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on several open source bits and pieces, I created a [OoXmlCrypto stream](http://code.google.com/p/ooxmlcrypto/) wrapper to access Office 2007 encrypted files easily.

This is based on a [blog post](http://www.lyquidity.com/devblog/?p=35) with [source code](http://www.lyquidity.com/devblog/wp-content/uploads/2008/12/ooxmlcrypto1.zip) which does OOXML encryption/decryption.

Comment: Have you used it since then? It is not so good documented, so I cannot figure out, when and how to use it ?

Comment: Any Usage Syntax for ooxmlcryto Stream library?

Answer (score 3):

Office 2007 uses an OLE document (the same container format that is used for the binary Office documents) to store encrypted documents.

[**[MS-OFFCRYPTO]: Office Document Cryptography Structure Specification**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc313071.aspx) should contain the specification of the used data structures and algorithms.

Comment: Thanks. That's a rather long spec. I'm still hoping for a black box :)

Comment: Well, one black box you can use would be to automate Office. But I don't know about any third-part library that can handle encryption.

Answer (score 1):

JFYI: our SecureBlackbox product offers [components for encryption and decryption of OOXML documents](http://www.eldos.com/sbb/desc-office.php) among many other functions.